# How do I copy the value of one column into another in the same row?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my example table:

```
+-----+----------+------+
| id  | current  | max  |
+-----+----------+------+
| 1   | 20       | 100  |
| 2   | 50       | 50   |
+-----+----------+------+
```

I am in need of a query that will set the value of a row's `current` column to its `max` column, but I can't find a way to copy it over. This is my current query:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `current` = ??? WHERE `id` = 1
```

What would I replace `???` with to use that column's value of 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it to that column value, using the column name:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `current` = `max` WHERE `id` = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

To update the column `current` with value in `max` column for only the row id **1**, use this script.

```
UPDATE table 
SET    current = max
WHERE  id = 1;
```

To update column `current` with value in `max` column for all the rows in the table, remove the `WHERE` condition.

```
UPDATE table 
SET    current = max;
```